# Fetch linked contacts with iOS9 Contacts framework

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts

Is there a way to fetch linked contacts of a unified contact in iOS9 Contacts framework?

This shows that it should be possible, however, I didn't find anything that could make it yet.

> If the identifier is for a unified contact then this method returns an
>   empty array. To fetch the containers of a unified contact, first fetch
>   the linked contacts and then fetch the container of each linked
>   contact.

From [Apple docs, CNContainer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContainer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CNContainer/predicateForContainerOfContactWithIdentifier:)